# what is the use of creating a new way of url pattern in this code and what does it symbolize?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

> > > Blockquote
> > > file path of the url
> > > hello guys i am just a beginner in django so i cant understad what is the use of using this url pattern in this code
> > > from django.conf import settings from django.conf.urls.static import static
>
> > urlpatterns += static(settings.MEIDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

since user-uploaded content is assumed to exist in a production context, to see media
items locally we need to update config/urls.py to show the files locally. This involves importing
both settings and static at the top and then adding an additional line at the bottom.